# Updating macros updates too much

Tags: macros

I am trying to use LaTeX to store and update the values of three banners, `\firstbanner`, `\secondbanner`, and `\thirdbanner`, using a `\addbanner` command to update `\firstbanner` and have the old `\firstbanner` value go into `\secondbanner`, the old `\secondbanner` into `\thirdbanner`. However, when I call `\addbanner` with a new value, all three banners end up having the same value. Here is the code I am using:

```
\newcommand{\thirdbanner}{three}
\newcommand{\secondbanner}{two}
\newcommand{\firstbanner}{one}
\newcommand{\printbanners}{
    Third banner :\thirdbanner \\
    Second banner :\secondbanner \\
    First banner :\firstbanner \\
}
\newcommand{\addbanner}[1]{
    \\ Adding #1: \\ \printbanners \\
    \renewcommand{\thirdbanner}{\secondbanner}
    renew third : \printbanners \\
    \renewcommand{\secondbanner}{\firstbanner}
     renew seconf: \printbanners \\
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{hello}
    renew first \printbanners
}

\addbanner{hello}
```

The output of above:

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome. // Why don‘t you just drop the \renewcommands and call each banner macro directly (kind of constant this way)? If you need different \print „calls“, just define as many as you need. It may be overdone in this example, and works well, once you need uniform output, defined in one place only. // You can do with one \print, when you allow arguments, which will be #1, #2 and #3 in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `\renewcommand{\thirdbanner}{\secondbanner}` you don't define `\thirdbanner` to have the current value of `\secondbanner`, but you're defining `\thirdbanner` to expand to `\secondbanner`.

You'd need to access the current value of `\secondbanner` with something like

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\thirdbanner\expandafter{\secondbanner}
```

or

```
\edef\thirdbanner{\unexpanded\expandafter{\secondbanner}}
```

I suggest a different strategy: use a sequence, to which you can add items on either end, in this case on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_egreg_banner_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\addbanner}{m}
 {
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g_egreg_banner_seq { #1 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getbanner}{m}
 {
  \seq_item:Nn \g_egreg_banner_seq { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\printbanners}{%
  Third banner: \getbanner{3}\par
  Second banner: \getbanner{2}\par
  First banner: \getbanner{1}\par
}

\begin{document}

\addbanner{three}
\addbanner{two}
\addbanner{one}

\printbanners

\bigskip

\addbanner{hello}

\printbanners

\bigskip

\addbanner{world}

\printbanners

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a bonus, you can access *all* banners you defined.

---

A legacy implementation, but with the disadvantage that only the top three items are kept.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% user level commands
\newcommand{\addbanner}[1]{%
  \expandafter\banner@add\expandafter{\banner@container}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\firstbanner}{%
  \expandafter\banner@first\banner@container\@nil
}
\newcommand{\secondbanner}{%
  \expandafter\banner@second\banner@container\@nil
}
\newcommand{\thirdbanner}{%
  \expandafter\banner@third\banner@container\@nil
}
% internal macros
\newcommand{\banner@container}{{}{}{}}% ensure at least three items
\newcommand\banner@add[2]{\banner@add@aux{#2}#1\@nil}
\def\banner@add@aux#1#2#3#4\@nil{%
  \gdef\banner@container{{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}
\def\banner@first#1#2#3#4\@nil{#1}
\def\banner@second#1#2#3#4\@nil{#2}
\def\banner@third#1#2#3#4\@nil{#3}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\printbanners}{%
  Third banner: \thirdbanner\par
  Second banner: \secondbanner\par
  First banner: \firstbanner\par
}

\begin{document}

\addbanner{three}
\addbanner{two}
\addbanner{one}

\printbanners

\bigskip

\addbanner{hello}

\printbanners

\bigskip

\addbanner{world}

\printbanners

\end{document}
```

Comment: Got an error when running your code "_ must be inside math mode" on the line "\seq_gput_left:Nn \g_egreg_banner_seq { #1 }" and it wouldn't compile. Then suddenly it worked (after changing the variable name to \my_seq, then back again after it worked) but the error is still there (in overleaf) wierd.

Comment: @user1081813 There is no `\my_seq` in my code. Anyway, you probably forgot `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: I published the comment before it was done by trying hitting return, I thought you could have linebreaks in comments

Comment: @user1081813 Sorry, but changing `\g_egreg_banner_seq` into `\my_seq` cannot influence errors, besides being against the naming conventions for variables.

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to the "wonderful" world of macros, which defines "text" expansion, i.e., replacements.

As a beginner, I was also used to program with "usual" programming languages like C, C++, C#, Pascal, or script languages like Python, and Perl. And when dealing with a macro language for the first time, this programming language is often ... mysterious and unexpected :-).

Results are unexpected because one thinks in terms of value assignments, as in C, when doing something like

```
int i = 1; 
int j = i; 
i = 2;
```

and one expects that `i` has now a value `2` whereas `j` has a value `1`.  Defining a macro doesn't assign the evaluated value on the right hand to the macro, but assigns the list of tokens as *replacement* to the macro.  And when "calling" the macro, the macro token will get replaced by the list of tokens valid from the last macro definition. Probably one can think of something like "lazy evaluation" when dealing with macros because when defining a macro, the replacement text won't get evaluated/expanded.

Thus after

```
\newcommand{\i}{1} 
\newcommand{\j}{\i}
\renewcommand{\i}{2}
```

the two macros `\i` and `\j` have the following replacement token lists:  `\i` gets replaced by `1` after the first `\newcommand` and finally by `2` after the `\renewcommand`, whereas `\j` will get replaced by `\i`, is not changed afterwards and will still get replaced by `\i` and *not* by the token list `1` as probably expected.

(To see the current definition of a macro you can use the primitive `\show\i` and `\show\j`, which will output the assigned replacement as a list of tokens.  If you are using a TeX GUI, you must check the log output.)

Answer (score 9):

You need to copy the definition of a command into another, not redefine it to show that command. This is typically achieved via `\let` or `\NewCommandCopy`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\thirdbanner}{three}
\newcommand{\secondbanner}{two}
\newcommand{\firstbanner}{one}
\newcommand{\printbanners}{%
    Third banner: \thirdbanner \\
    Second banner: \secondbanner \\
    First banner: \firstbanner
}
\newcommand{\addbanner}[1]{%
    Adding #1: \\
    \let\thirdbanner\secondbanner
    renew third: \thirdbanner \\
    \let\secondbanner\firstbanner
     renew second: \secondbanner \\
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{#1}%
    renew first: \firstbanner
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\printbanners

\bigskip

\addbanner{how}

\medskip

\addbanner{now}

\medskip

\addbanner{brown}

\medskip

\addbanner{cow}

\end{document}
```