# Renewcommand in \fancyhead not persisting into next page

Tags: macros, header-footer

I'm trying to write a latex document that has a banner in the header, with two to three small descriptions of what is on the page.

I want these descriptions to be written to the header dynamically. I want to add the descriptions with a function like `\addbanner{ Text for banner.}` through out the text. [I made such a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671014/updating-macros-updates-too-much), now my issue is clearing the values. I dont want any descriptions showing up on two page headers. When I make a function/macro for clearing the values, **if i call it inside \fancyhead the changes wont persist onto the next page**. It similarly wont persist if using the atbegshi package and calling \AtBeginShipout (not in code provided).

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \firstbanner \secondbanner \thirdbanner 
    \clearbanners
    \printbanners
}
\newcommand{\clearbanners}{  
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{}
    \renewcommand{\secondbanner}{}
    \renewcommand{\thirdbanner}{some text just to see that it disappears anyway in next page}
}

\newcommand{\thirdbanner}{three}
\newcommand{\secondbanner}{two}
\newcommand{\firstbanner}{one}

%it adds them kind of like a queue
\newcommand{\addbanner}[1]{%
   % Adding #1: \\
    \let\thirdbanner\secondbanner 
    %renew third: \thirdbanner \\
    \let\secondbanner\firstbanner
    % renew second: \secondbanner \\
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{#1}%
    %renew first: \firstbanner
}
```

At the end of the day I also want to see how many descriptions are on the page, after clearing all the ---banner macros on prev page there should be 0-3 (in practice 2 or 3) and an \if \else statemanent in the fancyhead function uses two different layouts depending.

[image: two banners]
[image: three banners]

Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \firstbanner \secondbanner \thirdbanner 
    \clearbanners
    \printbanners
}
\newcommand{\clearbanners}{  
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{}
    \renewcommand{\secondbanner}{}
    \renewcommand{\thirdbanner}{some text just to see that it disappears anyway in next page}
}
 
\newcommand{\thirdbanner}{three}
\newcommand{\secondbanner}{two}
\newcommand{\firstbanner}{one}
 
%for debigging
\newcommand{\printbanners}{%
    Third banner: \thirdbanner 
    Second banner: \secondbanner 
    First banner: \firstbanner 
}
 
\newcommand{\addbanner}[1]{%
   % Adding #1: \\
    \let\thirdbanner\secondbanner 
    %renew third: \thirdbanner \\
    \let\secondbanner\firstbanner
    % renew second: \secondbanner \\
    \renewcommand{\firstbanner}{#1}%
    %renew first: \firstbanner
}
 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
 
\begin{document}
 
\printbanners
 
\addbanner{how}
 
\addbanner{now}
 
\medskip
 
\printbanners
 
\newpage
 
\printbanners
 
The second page
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please don't use external links, you can add an example here

Comment: Please paste the mwe in here for future reference. pastebins tend to disappear after some time.

Comment: Code in the headers is executed inside the LaTeX output routine, which operates inside a TeX group (or multiple nested TeX groups). The changes made with `\renewcommand` are local, so they disappear at the end of the group. You would have to use the low level TeX command `\gdef` to get the desired effect. However,  as the `\addbanner` command is given in the running text, it may be executed asynchronously with respect to the page breaking, and some of them may end up on the wrong page.